# Central Limit Theorem & Random Walks

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, markov-process, random-walk

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^\infty$ be $\operatorname{i.i.d}$. Assume that $P(X_1 =1) = P(X_1 =-1) = \frac{1}{2} $ and define $S_n$ by

$$\begin{cases}
S_0 & = 0\\
S_n :&= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \,\,\,\, (n \ge 1).
\end{cases}
$$

Let $A: = \{ S_{100} =0\}  $, $B:= \{ S_{200} =0 \}$, are $A$ and $B$ independent? Answer with reason.

Find the value of $\underset{n \to n}{\lim} P(S_n \ge n^{1/3})$.
For each $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $T_x : \inf \{ n \ge 0 | S_n = x \}$, where $\inf \phi = \infty$. Show that $P(T_x < \infty) =1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For each $n \ge 1$, $M_n : = \frac{\max \{ S_k | 0 \le k \le n\}}{\sqrt{n}}$. Show that $\{P^{M_n} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ convergence weekly as $n \to \infty$ in the topology of probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})).$ ($\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is Borel algebra of $\mathbb{R}$).

I have been studying this problem since two weeks and these are my solutions to the three points of the problem. However, the fourth point is not easy, I do not even know where to look fo find the solution of similar solution. I need check for the solution of point 3 and help to solve point four. Thanks in advance.

(1)

Let $ C= \{\sum_{i=101}^{200} X_i =0 \}$. Then $A \cap B = A \cap C$, so  $P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap C) = P(A)P(C)$. For this to equal $P(A)P(B)$,we would need $P(B) = P(C)$, but this is false. So $A$ and $B$ are dependent.

(2)-

$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} P(S_n \ge n^{1/3}) = \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} P(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{n^{1/6}} \ge 0)$. By central limit theorem we have
$$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{distribution} N(0,1).$$

then

$$\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{1}{n^{1/6}} \right) \xrightarrow{d} (N(0,1), 0).$$

By the continuous mapping theorem (applied to $f(x,y) = x-y$).

$$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{n^{1/6}} \xrightarrow{distribution} N(0,1)$$

and then

$$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} P(S_n \ge n^{1/3}) = P(N(0,1) \ge 0)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

(3)- Before solving this point we need to recall some facts.

$$T_x = \inf \{n \ge 0: S_n =x \} = \text{Hitting time on x}.$$

Since $S_0=0$ then $T_x$ is also is the first passage time to $x$.

$$V_x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{ S_n=x\}} = \text{ Number of visits to x}.$$

$$f_x  = P_x(T_x < \infty) = \text{ return probability to x}.$$

$$m_x = E_x (T_x) = \text{ mean return time to } x.$$

$x$ is \textbf{recurrent} if $P_x (V_x =\infty)=1$. Otherwise $x$ is transient.
\begin{theorem}{(1)}
\label{1}
$$x \text{ is recurrent } \iff f_x =1.$$

$$x \text{ transient } \iff f_x < 1.$$
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
$$P_x (V_x <\infty) = P_x \left( \bigcup_{k \ge 1} { V_x =k } \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P_x (V_x =k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1- f_x) f_x^{k-1}= \begin{cases} 0, & f_x =1\
1, & f_x <1
\end{cases}.$$

So $x$ is recurrent iff $f_x=1$, and transient iff $f_x <1$.
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}{(2)}
\label{2}
$$x \text{ recurrent } \iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{xx}^{(n)} =\infty \iff f_x =1.$$

$$x \text{ transient } \iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{xx}^{(n)} <\infty \iff f_x <1.$$
\begin{proof}
If $x$ is recurrent, this means $P_x (V_x =\infty)=1$, and so

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{xx}^{(n)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty E_x \left( 1_{\{ S_n=x \}} \right) = E_x \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{S_n=x \}} \right) = E_x (V_x)=\infty.$$
If $x$ is transient then by Theorem (1) $f_i <1$ and

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{xx}^{(n)} = E_x (V_x) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty P_x (V_x > r) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty f_x^r =\frac{1}{1-f_x} < \infty.$$

\end{proof}

\end{theorem}

Now we start solve the problem. By the Markov property we have

$$P(T_x < \infty) = \sum_{y \in \mathbb{Z}} P(X_0=y) P_y (T_x <\infty).$$
so it suffices to show that $P_y(T_x < \infty)=1$ for all $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Choose $m$ with $p^{(m)}_{xy} > 0$. By Theorem ( 2 ) we have

\begin{align*}
    1 &= P_x (S_n = x \text{ for infinitely many } n)\\
      &\le P_x (S_n=x \text{ for some } n \ge m+1)\\
      & = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} P_x (S_n = x \text{ for some } n \ge m+1 | S_m = k) P_x (S_m = k)\\
      &= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} P_k ( T_x < \infty) p^{(m)}_{jk}
\end{align*}

But $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} p^{(m)}_{jk}=1$ so we must have $P_y (T_x <\infty)=1$.

(4)-

Comment: 1. [You have the right idea, but you have a lot of typos.] Let $C=\{\sum_{i=101}^{200} X_i = 0\}$. Then $A\cap B = A\cap C$, so $P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap C) = P(A) P(C)$. For this to equal $P(A) P(B)$ we would need $P(B)=P(C)$, but this is false.
2. Your work looks good except for the very last step: it should be $P(N(0,1) \ge 0) = 1/2$.

Comment: For the third question, what is $\phi$?

Comment: @angryavian empty set

Comment: @angryavian Could you solve the other two points for me please.

Comment: For 3, condition on $X_1$ to get $P(T_1 < \infty) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} P(T_2 < \infty)$ and note that $P(T_2 < \infty) = P(T_1 < \infty)^2$. Then note that $P(T_x < \infty) = P(T_1 < \infty)^x$ for integers $x \ge 1$.

Comment: @angryavian It the condition existed or I need to make it?

Comment: I mean "condition" as in "conditional probability," i.e. $P(T_1<\infty) = P(T_1 < \infty \mid X_1 = 1) P(X_1=1) + P(T_1 < \infty \mid X_1 = -1) P(X_1=-1)$.

Comment: The random walk goes from $0$ to $2$ in finite time if and only if it goes from $0$ to $1$ in finite time, and then from $1$ to $2$ in finite time.

Answer (score 1):

For part 4, the following result holds for any i.i.d. $\left\{X_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$ with $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}\right]=0$, $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}^{2}\right]=1$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(M_{n}<m\right)=\begin{cases}0& \text{if }m\leq0\\\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{m}e^{-u^{2}/2}du & \text{if }m>0\end{cases}.$$